Counterexample of Weak Convergence when Function is not Bounded
Ex. 10.1.6

Let $M > 0$, and let $f, f_1, f_2, \cdots :[0, 1] \rightarrow [\frac{1}{M}, M]$ be Borel measurable functions with $\int_0^1 f \; d\lambda = \int_0^1 f_n \; d \lambda = 1$. Suppose $\lim_n \frac{f_n (x)}{f(x)} = 1$ for each fixed $x \in [0, 1]$. Define probability measures $\mu, \mu_1,\mu_2, \cdots$ by $\mu (A) = \int_A f\; d \lambda$ and $\mu_n (A) = \int_A f_n \; d \lambda$, for Borel $A \subseteq [0, 1]$. Prove that $\mu \Rightarrow \mu$.

Ex. 10.1.7

Give an example to show that the result of the previous exercise is false if the functions $f, f_1, f_2, \cdots$ are strictly positive but are not required to be between $\frac{1}{M}$ and $M$.

I have attempted Ex. 10.1.6, but can't find counterexample for Ex. 10.1.7, esp. that I am struggling with the condition that $\lim_n \frac{f_n (x)}{f(x)} = 1$.
My attempt on Ex. 10.1.6

For $x \in [0, 1]$, assume that $A = [0, x)$. 
Then $|\mu_n (A)| = |\int_A f_n \; d \lambda| = |\int_0^x f_n \; d \lambda| \leq ( M - \frac{1}{M} )x \leq ( M - \frac{1}{M} )$.  
$\therefore \mu_n (A)|$ is bounded. 
By assumption, $\lim_n \frac{f_n (x)}{f(x)} = 1$ 
$\therefore \forall \varepsilon > 0: \exists N\in \mathbb{Z}^+: n \geq N\Rightarrow | \dfrac{f_n (x)}{f(x)} - 1| < \varepsilon$, i.e. $|f_n (x) - f(x)| \leq \varepsilon |f(x)| < \varepsilon M$. 
$\therefore f_n (x) \rightarrow f(x)$. 
$\therefore$ By bounded conv. thm, $\lim_n \int_0^x f_n \; d \lambda = \int_0^x f \; d \lambda$. 
$\therefore \mu_n \Rightarrow \mu$.

Obviously, "$|f_n (x) - f(x)| \leq \varepsilon |f(x)| < \varepsilon M$" makes that $f_n$ and $f$ being bounded are necessary.
Another help for counterexample? Thanks.
Source: Rosenthal, J. S. (2000). A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory. World Scientific.

This exercise is wrong. We have $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for each $x$ and $\int f_n=\int f=1$. Scheffe's Lemma shows that $\int |f-f_n|
\to 0$ which implies that $\mu_n(A) \to \mu (A)$ for every Borel set $A$.
Ref. for Scheffe's Lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma
